# Updated: How do I pass a default value into my modal input element

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

UPdated: have been stuck on this for 3 day's now and I cannot find an answer anywhere.
I have a model that  contains -input type="text" name="mycardname" id="CardName"/-
I want to post the card name into the value of the input box.
I can put it in a label or a span, but cannot find a way or example to add it to the input box.
My code is below.

```js
    var ATTRIBUTES = ['cardname', 'metric', 'month'];

    $('.CardModal').on('click', function (e) {

        var $target = $(e.target);
        var modalSelector = $target.data('target');
        ATTRIBUTES.forEach(function (attributeName) {
            var $modalAttribute = $(modalSelector + ' #modal-' + attributeName);

            var dataValue = $target.data(attributeName);
            $modalAttribute.text(dataValue || '');

            $target('#CardName')('value try This');
        });
    });

    $('#settingsModal,#monthModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        alert("this alert");
        var $card = $(event.relatedTarget).closest('.card');
        var $modal = $(this);

        var data = $card.data();
        Document.getElementById('#CardName').val("try This");




        for (var item in data) {
            $modal.find('[name="' + item + '"]').val(data[item]);
        }
    });

    $('#monthModal .btn-primary').click(function () {
        var $modal = $(this).closest('.modal');

        var searchType = $modal.find('input[name="SearchTypeRadio"]:checked').val();


        var metric = $modal.find('[name="metric"]').val();
        var month = $modal.find('[name="month"]').val();
        var cdName = $modal.find('[name="mycardname"]').val();

        alert("SearchType: " + searchType + " Metric: " + metric + " Month: " + month + " Card Name: " + cdName);



    });

    $('.btnApplyColors').on('click', function () {


        var $modal = $(this).closest('.modal');
        var cardName = $modal.find('[name="name"]').val();
        var grMin = $modal.find('[name="greenmin"]').val();
        var grMax = $modal.find('[name="greenmax"]').val();
        var yMin = $modal.find('[name="yellowmin"]').val();
        var yMax = $modal.find('[name="yellowmax"]').val();
        var rMin = $modal.find('[name="redmin"]').val();
        var rMax = $modal.find('[name="redmax"]').val();

        var cardTR = cardName + 'TR';


        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(cardTR); // get all elements
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var tsd1 = cardName + i + 'TD1';
            var tsd2 = cardName + i + 'TD2';

            var td1 = document.getElementById(tsd1).innerHTML;
            var td2 = parseInt(document.getElementById(tsd2).innerHTML);


            alert(td1 + " - " + td2);

            switch (true) {

                case (td2 >= yMin && td2 <= yMax):
                    alert(td1 + " - " + td2 + " YMin " + yMin + " yMax " + yMax);
                    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightyellow";
                    elements[i].style.color = 'brown';

                    break;

                case (td2 >= grMin && td2 <= grMax):
                    alert(td1 + " - " + td2 + " grMin " + grMin + " grMax " + grMax);
                    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "#E7FCE3";
                    elements[i].style.color = 'darkgreen';

                    break;

                case (td2 >= rMin && td2 <= rMax):
                    alert(td1 + " - " + td2 + " rMin " + rMin + " rMax " + rMax);
                    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "mistyrose";
                    elements[i].style.color = 'red';

                    break;
                default:
                    alert("Hit the Default because " + td2 + " not found");
                    break;
            }
        }

        $('#ScoreCardDefaults').modal('hide');



    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
            var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
            var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
            $(".box").not(targetBox).hide();
            $(targetBox).show();
        });
    });

    //  clean this up //

    let startYear = 2000;
    let endYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    for (i = endYear; i > startYear; i--) {
        $('#yearpicker').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-xl-4">


        <div class="col mb-4" data-mincoolscale="71">
            <div class="card text-center" data-metric="14" data-month="2020-10" data-mincoolscale="71" data-maxcoolscale="100" data-minwarmscale="51" data-maxwarmscale="70" data-minhotscale="0" data-maxhotscale="50">
                <div class="card-img-top d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center bg-primary text-light metric-header">
                    <span class="h5 my-1">my card</span>
                </div>

                <div class="card-body pt-3">
                    <h6 class="card-title">
                        my card title
                    </h6>

                    <p>
                        <span class="metric-date">@DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM yyyy")</span>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-link CardModal" data-cardname="The Card Name" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#monthModal" title="Edit" aria-title="Edit">
                            Ccc
                        </button>
                    </p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="monthModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="monthModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="monthModalTitle">Display Statistics For</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <span id="modal-cardname"></span>
                <input type="text" name="mycardname" id="CardName" />


                <div class="myRadios">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="SearchTypeRadio" value="Monthly"> Monthly</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="SearchTypeRadio" value="Quarterly"> Quarterly</label>

                </div>
                <div style="display:none" class="Monthly box">You have selected Monthly</div>
                <div style="display:none" class="Quarterly box">You have selected quarterly</div>



                <div style="display:none" class="Monthly box form-group">
                    <input type="month" id="month" name="month" class="form-control w-auto" placeholder="mm/yyyy" max="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM")" min="2010-01" />
                </div>

                <div style="display:none" class="Quarterly box form-group">
                    @*<label for="month">Yearly Quarter of</label>*@
                    <select id="QTRS">
                        <option value="1" selected>1st Quarter</option>
                        <option value="2">2nd Quarter</option>
                        <option value="3">3rd Quarter</option>
                        <option value="4">4th Quarter</option>
                    </select>

                    <select name="yearpicker" id="yearpicker"></select>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

                @*<a class=" btn btn-primary" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="updateSSOA"> Apply</a>*@

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Apply</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This editor keeps deleting some of my content..... How do I show my code examples???

Comment: Could you please share your whole view?Otherwise,the jquery code would make different influence.

Comment: Just updated with the Code (Visual Studio 2019, .net core 3.1, MVC)

Comment: Just noticed the DOM object shows ~input id="modal-cardname" name="mycardname"~SSOAKLS~/input~ ...... SSOAKLS is the name I passed in. It is between the opening tag and the closing tag (not in the value="" attribute)  If I manually type the value into the value="SSOAKLS" it will work. Having the data between the open and close tags does not work. (It also does not show up on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if there are multiple text boxes and buttons that are the same on this page. Do you mean to traverse all `ATTRIBUTES` to the text box corresponding to this button or to pass the `ATTRIBUTES` corresponding to the modal value into the text box?

If you pass in a corresponding `ATTRIBUTES`, please refer to the following example:

```
<input type="text" name="mycardname" id="CardName" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-link CardModal"
        data-cardname="kls01" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#monthModal"
        title="Edit" aria-title="Edit">
    Launch Modal
</button>
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var ATTRIBUTES = ['cardname', 'metric', 'month'];
            $('.CardModal').on('click', function (e) {
                var $target = $(e.target); 
                var modalSelector = $target.data('target'); 
                ATTRIBUTES.forEach(function (attributeName) {
                    var $modalAttribute = $(modalSelector + ' #modal-' + attributeName);
                    var dataValue = $target.data(attributeName); 
                    $modalAttribute.text(dataValue || '00');
                    if ($target.prev().val() == '' || $target.prev().val == null) {
                        $target.prev().val(attributeName || '')
                    }
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Good question, and yes I plan to eventually have input boxes for each....I don't see any change in this code???  This gives me the same result, no value in the input box on the modal.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out:

Change:
$target('#CardName')('value try This');

to:

var myCardName = $(this).data('cardname');

$(".modal-body #mycardname").val(myCardName);